# Problem while displaying activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

Hi I have a Broadcast receiver with following code.

```
   1. Intent i = new Intent(context, A.class);    
   2. i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
   3. context.startActivity(i);
```

This works fine and my activity does start, but it starts on top of my main activity i.e. B. What I want is that from my broadcast receiver I should be able start an Activity A, such that it does not start on top of B. Why B is always starting in background. What I am doing wrong.

Also, to mention by activity A has Theme.Dialog.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Are both activities started when you run the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new activity is supposed to start on top of existing activities.

If you want to start something without appearing in the activity history stack, maybe this something shouldn't be an `Activity` but a `Service` instead?

Edit: I think you can change this behaviour with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in conjunction with `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the Manifest. (see [documentation on launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode))

Comment: This discussion is going in a different direction. Let me try to rephrase again...

Comment: I want to start an activity to show the user some user interface when an intent is received by BR. I have an app which has multiple activites, one of them which is currently main activity i.e. Activity B. Let us say my app has 5 activities A,B,C,D,E. Now, I am on home screen with no activity history stack and an event is received by BR. Now I want to display activity A. This happens but activity B (which is my main activity) always appears on back of Activity A (even when there is no history stack, as I was on home screen when an intent was received) Hope this clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, launchMode did helped me. I am using android:launchMode="singleInstance" which works for me fine. Now a new problem is, once I hit back and press HOME button to see recent apps, when I select my App button, it takes me to Activity A, whereas I want to go to Activity B (which is my main activity).

Answer (score 0):

If you start an Activity then of course it will come foreground.The activity previously was in foreground will go to the background automatically.

If you don't need to start it on top of B,what about to start it from service?.Let Activity A stay as it is.

If you need to access anything from service and no need to show the activity,then surely you are looking for other then starting an Activity with an intent.

Finally if you really want to start Activity A,and B will be on top then start Activity B after starting A

Comment: No, this behavior is happening on the home screen. So I am on the home screen, and receive an intent in my broadcastreceiver which starts activity A using the code mentioned above. But everytime, it starts with Activity B in background. Please note that activity B is a main activity and activity A is not a main activity.

Comment: I indeed want to start an activity to show the user some user interface when an intent is received by my broadcastreceiver. I have an application which has multiple activites, one of them which is currently main activity i.e. Activity B. Let us say my app has 5 activities a,b,c,d,e. Now, I am on home screen with no activity history stack and an event is received by BR. Now I want to display activity A. This happens but activity B (which is my main activity) always appears on back of Activity A (even when there is no history stack, as I was on home screen when an intent was received)

Comment: Thanks, launchMode did helped me. I am using android:launchMode="singleInstance" which works for me fine. Now a new problem is, once I hit back and press HOME button to see recent apps, when I select my App button, it takes me to Activity A, whereas I want to go to Activity B (which is my main activity).

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you mean you want to start the application with a different activity. You can edit your AndroidManifest.xml file to make a different activity start first.

EDIT: Heres an example:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" <-this will start first
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name =".otherActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".anotherActivity"></activity>
</application>
```